# Why are only homework-related questions required to state an attempt?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) currently states that

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

**Why is this specific to homework?**

Does this imply that questions giving a proper specification asking for a implementation in some programming language X with tools Y are on-topic, given the specification is not part of any homework assignment and not too complex for the question to be considered as too broad? If so, why is homework treated differently?

Comment: I think its just written up that way because a majority of the questions that showed no attempt were from people who were trying to get their homework done for them. It doesn't specify that "non-homework" questions need to show their attempts but more often than not the community will take care of that by downvoting lack of effort.

Comment: @DasBeasto From what I understood, Downvoting means that the question does not have a high *quality*, while *off-topic* questions should get closed. Did I miss something there?

Comment: Maybe this is left-over from when the `homework` tag still existed.

Comment: @dst When you hover the downvote button it says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: So what's the process to get the help text amended?  Should a separate question with [tag:feature-request] be posted with a proposal for new text?  Or is it just enough to suggest something here?

Comment: "Questions asking for (e.g.) homework help" would be an easy fix.

Answer (score 19):

You're overthinking this.

We're not looking for evidence that the user has put in effort; we're looking for evidence that the user *will understand the answer we give them,* and that he is not just asking us to do all of their work for them.  That's not quite the same thing as demonstration of effort, although demonstration of effort and showing prior research is a great way to demonstrate understanding of the problem space.

The prohibition against homework assignments with no effort is aimed squarely at folks who *copy paste their homework assignments,* hoping someone here will just hand them the solution.

Comment: Except that most programmers of even dubious professionalism are not cheeky enough to believe that they can just paste their project requirements into a question and expect someone to code up a solution for them.  That hardly ever happens, and when it does, such questions are easily closeable as Too Broad.  On the other hand, copy/pastes of homework problems are disturbingly common.  Even worse, they usually will attract an answer unless they get closed first.

Comment: Too Broad is a valid and effective remedy for such questions.  Using Too Broad for copy/paste homework questions is dubious, since they are seldom too broad; which is why homework is called out specifically.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that only homework questions must, it's that all questions must and people who ask homework questions are generally more likely to ignore those rules because they're inherently less likely to be answering questions on the site.

In general, part of why we like to see attempts is because we want to be the absolute last resort. So theoretically, an attempt would already have been made, so showing it isn't extra work, and it clears answerers from having to duplicate work that the OP already did.

Long story short, we don't like to be given assignments any more than you do. Asking questions on here is great, and I know a lot of people really, honestly enjoy answering them. But there's a point where someone is just asking us to do their homework for them, or asking us to write their application for them. And that's not so fun.

Comment: It's not exactly _required_, but it's a [really good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179038/159251) to show your research. And it should be noted that this doesn't necessarily mean code -- but in the case of homework it's very likely to mean that.