# Are we getting overly aggressive in comments towards homework questions (again)?

Tags: discussion, comments

There was a [relatively basic question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26109575/1079354) (10K users only) posted on SO today, and I had made a comment in hopes of prodding the asker to a solution.

> [image: relatively basic question]

I came back to it about ten minutes later and saw this comment, which had *five* upvotes:

> Assignment doesn't count as a question... Please read How to Ask

**Wait** a minute.

Since when do questions about assignments not count as actual questions?

I'm not going to deny that the question wasn't great, but does that mean it should have been written off outright?  It seems like it was an extremely aggressive stance towards a question that *looked* like a homework problem (but it turns out that it wasn't).

What is the community's thoughts on this?  I realize that we allow homework questions if they're up to standards, but is this sort of behavior acceptable on *any* question?

---

So I'm noticing that a lot of people here are missing the point.  I'm not saying that the homework question was justified or fine; I support the current rules around homework questions needing to be up to standards, and I also actively *enforce* that where possible.

What ***I'm*** asking about is whether or not the kinds of comments I've seen on homework questions, such as the one above, are remotely justified.  It seems to me that it's overly aggressive, when a gentler comment explaining what the standards of the site are would suffice just as well.

Comment: "Since when do questions about assignments not count as actual questions?" Where does the comment say that? The comment says that just dumping an assignment doesn't count as a question. And it's right.

Comment: First, the comments after the fact indicate that it wasn't a homework assignment.  Second, I **wholeheartedly agree** that dumping a homework assignment is simply not what this site is for.  But what I'm asking here is, what should one do in the face of such a remark?  Let it go?  Is this the kind of behavior we're okay with on questions like this?

Comment: In a case where someone is just dumping an assignment with no information, and expecting someone to either do their work for them or give them a complete tutorial from first principles, then the right thing to do in the face of such a remark is to upvote it. If the comment is wrong, that's a different story. But an assignment dump and a question about assignments are not at all the same thing, and your question is directly equating them.

Comment: Again - I notice that you're assuming that it is an assignment.  It's a poorly-phrased question which, while may *read* like an assignment, really isn't.  What I'm trying to get at is the crux of the matter; do we really want comments like that on questions because they *look* like homework assignments?

Comment: I'm assuming that it's an assignment because you framed your entire question as being about assignments. Your subject is "Are we getting overly aggressive in comments towards homework questions (again)?" Your main point is "Since when do questions about assignments not count as actual questions?" Is the problem that this wasn't really an assignment, but a different kind of bad question? If so, that's not what your question says.

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted? Surely questions about the tone of comments are important on any meta SE.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not too sure about overly aggressive, compared to a lot of the comments I've seen posted on homework/gimmie teh codez questions that comment looks pretty tame...

On average I don't think whether a question is homework or not really matters to most users.

What gets users on the war path tends to be the sense of entitlement, the

> I need code that does X, Y and Z.
>   Write it for me plz!

Whether its a homework assignment or specs from a customer, a lot of users don't want to put up with SO being treated like a free code writing service.

But, unfortunately a lot of these questions are easy to answer and they do get answered and even upvoted* reenforcing a cycle of questions that are usually too broad, not well researched, and often poorly written.

Sure you can try to do the right thing and just downvote, vote to close, and walk away, but there's that nagging feeling that chances are your downvote will be offset by someones sympathy vote and your close vote will probably age away before the question gathers another 4 close votes...

Hence the temptation to stir the pot by leaving a comment.

I'm not saying that it's right, but it happens. The blatantly offensive ones should be flagged as "rude or offensive" the others should probably be flagged as "not constructive" or "too chatty".

But while you're there flagging comments, please take the time to vote to close.

Often the best solution for these situations is to get the question closed as quickly as possible. The user who asked is spared the rude comments and hurt feelings and the users who are trying to keep SO together will feel a little less aggravated.

<sub>*I suspect the upvotes are often from the same people who posted the answers.</sub>

Answer (score 20):

Questions asking for homework help are expected to include a summary of the work that the student has undertaken so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty they are having solving it.

Questions that are *merely a copy/paste of the homework question,* with no additional information provided, are summarily closed.

This is one of those rare occasions where we do, in fact, require demonstration of effort.

Comment: I realize this.  What I'm asking about specifically is if the comment was appropriate, and what one should do if we see something like that.

Comment: I would need to know which question it was to weigh in on that.

Comment: When I can get to my box, you'll have the link.

Comment: *This is one of those rare occasions where we do, in fact, require demonstration of effort."*, I hope this was sarcasm...

Comment: @codeMagic: Nope.  Absolutely serious.

Comment: We don't *normally* expect demonstration of effort? As far as I'm concernded, and I thought most, a homework question is really no different than a non-homework question.

Comment: @codeMagic.  No.  Requiring people to show how they tried to solve their problem turns Stack Overflow from a question and answer site into a highly-localized troubleshooting forum.  For a more nuanced view explaining the copy\paste homework problem, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269361

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not completely sure I understand that but I'm also not positive that elaborating in comments on this post is appropriate (So far I've only read the Q and your A). But I don't see the difference of a professor giving a student an assignment or a boss giving an employee a task (where we don't know that the latter situation has given any effort and is typically closed for a couple different reasons).

Comment: @codeMagic: The main difference is that work orders can typically be closed as Too Broad, while homework assignments generally cannot.

Comment: OK, I can see that in that professors typically give certain ways that the problem need to be solved and in a workplace the circumstances can be more open. But, if you don't know that it's homework and you are free to give any answer which works, then it's the same situation. Either way, I think we want people to show us that they have tried *something* which is why we have the close reason, "...why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: @codeMagic: It sounds like you think that troubleshooting questions are the only thing you can ask on Stack Overflow.  I wouldn't blame you for thinking that, since that comprises the vast majority of questions we get nowadays.

Comment: No, I don't think those are the *only* questions. But I think when it comes to troubleshooting questions, homework vs. non-homework should be given the same consideration.

Comment: I'm continually stunned by the breadth and complexity of code posted on SO without ANY CLUE WHATSOEVER as to how to debug it.  OK, gdb is crap, debugging with printf/cout is worse, but the same issue applies to posters using an IDE where the debugger is buit-in.  Some might say that most of such code is copied from other students or net pages and the posters are totally clueless as to how it works and just want to suck on SO contributors to get their assignments completed.  I couldn't possibly comment...

Comment: For about the bilionth time, it's not homework questions, it's not about simple/complex, it's BAD QUESTIONS THAT JUST TAKE THE PISS OUT OF SO CONTRIBUTORS.

Comment: @codeMagic the 'best' questions are ones like "How do I split the words in a string in Java?  I can't use `split` or `Pattern` or `StringTokenizer`." Its almost as if the person missed a lecture or two.

Comment: So, I've added the link to the question at hand.  Bear in mind that this wasn't about homework questions in general; this is about comments on homework questions that come across as unnecessary, unhelpful, or downright inflammatory.

Comment: @Makoto oh - I can easily do 'unhelpful, or downright inflammatory'. 'unnecessary', however, is a different matter.  Bad questions, homework or not,  are sucking the blood out of skilled and experienced contributors.  I feel no guilt whatsoever when telling such posters to 'go away' in an assertive manner.

Comment: Look at this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119772/calling-convention-in-a-c-program#comment40936924_26119772

Answer (score 13):

You've clearly misinterpreted the comment:

> Assignment doesn't count as a question... Please read How to Ask

Your reply is:

> Since when do questions about assignments not count as actual questions?

Questions about assignments are not the same thing as assignment dumps. Questions about assignments can be good questions, even great questions. Assignment dumps cannot; the only way to answer them is to do the asker's homework for him, or write out a complete tutorial or link to an off-site tutorial so he can do the homework himself, neither of which is remotely appropriate for SO.

---

You then ask, "what should one do in the face of such a remark?" Well, such remarks are often correct, in which case you can choose to upvote them or ignore them. It's more important to downvote the question and vote to close. And, if you feel inclined, you can give the asker some help in the comments (as four different people did in this case). But I don't see anything wrong with upvoting a comment explaining what's wrong with a question.

---

In the comments, you changed to a different subject: as it turns out, this particular question wasn't an assignment at all, because the OP is trying to teach himself. OK, so in this case, the comment was wrong. I don't see how that's relevant to "Since when do questions about assignments not count as actual questions?"

Answer (score 6):

This might not be as constructive as the previous answers, but as the one who made the comment I just want to clarify a few things:

First: I do realize that my comment may come across as snarky (or even outright rude) and maybe I should have chosen my words better, or exercised a bit more restraint. The intent was neither to be aggressive, nor rude, but to state something I felt was obvious, with a helpful link on how to correct the problem. Not being a native English speaker maybe inappropriate sense for, or bad command of the language made it come out a bit more harsh than intended.

Second: I have no issues whatsoever with homework (or exercise type) questions, when they're presented in a manner that isn't just a verbatim copy of the assignment or exercise text. The lack of a proper problem statement was what triggered me.

I do believe that questions that reference a school assignment indeed can be valuable as they tend to go over basic stuff that possibly many people can benefit from (although if the source of a question is indeed a school assignment chances are that there might be better sources for answers, like tutors and ta´s).

And finally: As it turned out the question wasn't an assignment per se, so I guess I was wrong about that, and maybe I did overreact, but posting an assignment or exercise text without any further commentary about the nature of the problem to me at least just seems like *do my work for me* and sometimes, after reading one too many such questions, snarky comments are what happens (and I guess not just to me).

On this particular question I did a down vote and left my comment, realizing that it would probably get closed in a matter of minutes; however I'm not sure I fully agree with the unclear as the close reason as there really wasn't anything unclear about it at all, but maybe that's just due to a more appropriate reason.

My general feeling though is that there has been an increase in badly worded comments pointing out faults in questions or perceived lack of effort, which makes SO seem like a rather unfriendly place at times (and I'm sure I've been guilty of this myself sometimes). To some extent I guess this comes down to tit for tat. If someone doesn't make any effort when asking for time and commitment from someone else chances are the response will be of the same kind, right or wrong.