# Old dead meta links - should we encourage screenshots when posting links to questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I frequently come across questions (mostly on meta) which have deleted linked questions. Since the links do not disappear on their own (i.e. a viewer can still tell it's a link, albeit a dead one), a later visitor has no way of knowing what the link contained.

Then I came across this:

[Are we getting overly aggressive in comments towards homework questions (again)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272421/are-we-getting-overly-aggressive-in-comments-towards-homework-questions-again)

There has been an included screenshot, and it's evident that the question in the screenshot has been deleted already. So should there be a standard for this? Or will it just consume space on image servers with images no one will be really interested in?

Here's a screenshot of the above question:

[image: homework meta question]

Comment: It might be nice for `specific-question` posts to at least quote the relevant part of the question, if only because meta effect often results in the question getting deleted shortly after. Not sure that this needs to be a requirement though. Someone usually asks for a screenshot if it becomes necessary and it gets added.

Answer (score 2):

The links are not dead - deleted questions are still in the system, but they cannot be viewed by users with less than [10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). So including a screenshot would help <10k-users in taking part in the discussion *if the question was already deleted at that time* - this seems to be the case for your example, but quite often it isn't.

FYI, this is how the question looks like right now (note the difference in design):

[image]

Comment: We already encourage people to post blocks in answers alongside links so that the answer retains its value after the link goes dead(or is not viewable, whatever the case may be). I was thinking of a similar thing. 10K is quite a high point to reach for most - it's not a common thing on any SE site. I, as a viewer of the question, would like to be able to still view the content - for reference purposes - if the question was VLQ, for example, and was cleared out to discourage 'help vampires'.