# What is the point of "here is a bad [question|answer]"-type Meta questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, meta

Leaving aside the fact that these type of questions are pretty much rhetorical, I am talking about the fact that these questions reference parts of Stack Overflow that are promptly deleted. Generally these items will be deleted before they are archived by any third party service, leaving a question that has zero context after a minimum of a couple of hours.

> Q:  Hi, should [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/w00t/) be allowed?
>
> I don't think so, but I'd like some opinions.
>
> ---
>
> A: Yeah, it looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374/how-can-i-game-the-stack-overflow-system-to-achieve-higher-ranking-and-extra-bad/). In my opinion his talk about elephants  is, in particular, to be discouraged. Nice video though.

There are bucket loads of them, and they all seem to have no long-term significance. There's [one of them trending right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something?cb=1). In fairness to the author it quoted the answer (to a question that isn't quoted). The actual meta question is "whether a single word answer is good", which doesn't bear asking in the first place.

Comment: A) you can always ask for a screenshot, someone may notice.  B) people with over 10K can still see the content so chunk of the active community still has access.  C) Why would it not be okay to ask other people if the content of the question or answer is okay?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have no problem with C) other than the fact that it is tending towards an echo chamber. It may simply be the case that those who aren't senior enough just aren't welcome on meta. This question certainly got a lot of negative backlash and has now been closed for being 'off topic' and even has a vote to delete it (as it is, presumably, so offensive ). I'll revisit meta, I suppose, when I have over 10K reputation and am considered a proper member.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Leaving aside the fact that these type of meta questions are pretty much rhetorical,

I think you missed the point of Meta. The rules that we follow on the site are based on *discussions* here. This is a place for discussion. People post questions about what to do with content on the main site, and we discuss it.

> I am talking about the fact that these questions reference parts of [Stack Overflow] which are promptly deleted. Generally these items will be deleted before they are archived by any third party service, leaving a question that has zero context after a minimum of a couple of hours.

10k+ users have the ability to see deleted posts. If there's a question here that you feel is missing context, you can always post a comment asking for a 10k+ user to post a screenshot. Sometimes however, you'll see questions here where the asker has *explicitly* avoided linking to the post being discussed to avoid the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

> Q: Hi, should this question be allowed?

I'd vote to close that question for being too broad. There's nothing to discuss, so the discussion tag is not really there, and they didn't state any reason why they think it should or should not be allowed.

> There are bucket loads of them, and they all seem to have no long-term significance. There's one of them trending right now. In fairness to the author it quoted the answer (to a question which isn't quoted). The actual meta question is "whether a single word answer is good", which doesn't bear asking in the first place.

Actually, and here's the important bit, the question is explicitly *NOT* about single word answers. It's about what to do when someone posts an answer with "NO" repeated multiple times, and why a flag was declined. The question is asking whether it should be considered rude or abusive to answer like that, and what the proper course of action is in that case.

Comment: Discussions as intellectually stimulating as "I think Hitler is bad. Do you agree" in a forum concerning the Holocaust. But getting to my actual question, it seems the actual answer is that meta is a closed-shop, not meant for casual users. The downvotes to my question are along the lines of "I don't care about the validity of your question, I dislike the angle that you are taking". Only allowing people with >10K rep to see deleted is a curious form of censorship, which goes some distance to underline the general mentality in meta. Thankfully SO itself has a far more general user base.

Comment: @Stumbler Why do you care about downvotes here on Meta?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is [Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), so it is the place for

> Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (asking questions about ... policies and community decisions)

While they usually start because of a single question or answer on the main site, if there's enough consensus they become a sort of guideline, which can be used in future discussions. Believe me, the next time that somebody starts a discussion on Meta about a single word answer, it *will* be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something?cb=1).

Questions like this still keep their context even if the answer is deleted, which was bound to happen in this case because of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). But, users with >10k reputation can [view deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), and you can always ask them for a screenshot (in fact, there has even been a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320663/old-dead-meta-links-should-we-encourage-screenshots-when-posting-links-to-ques/320671#320671) about always including such screenshots) if you need more details to participate in the discussion yourself.

Comment: @Stumbler good question. You don't seem to care what other people think, so if you want to rant go somewhere else.

Comment: @jonrsharpe People having opinions is irrelevant in Q&A. Having positions that one can defend with evidence is another thing.  Like debating with a flat-earther, it is a pointless exercise, but the experience is worth something, I guess.

Comment: @Stumbler then perhaps you shouldn't have asked a question tagged with *"A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective..."* and then acting like a jerk (and proving Godwin right once again) when the immediate response wasn't *"Of course, you're a genius, why didn't we think of that"*? Meta is primarily aimed at gathering community consensus; if that's not something you're interested in, it's probably not the place for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Huh? A response of "Of course, you're a genius, why didn't we think of that?" would hardly rank as a discussion. That would be termed "agreement", and possibly knee-jerk agreement without any sort of critical assessment.  The argument would be "it can be seen that a large percentage of users who visit these questions have less than 10K reputation (many not even being logged in), and it is provable that the meaning of the question is dependent upon the information contained in the material that was deleted, therefore it is probable...".

Comment: @Stumbler then clarify what it is that you're proposing: a ban on asking MSO questions that mention SO questions that might be deleted? A ban on deleting SO questions that are mentioned in MSO questions? Some mechanism for automatically including the content from the SO question in the MSO question? *"What is the point"* is not a constructive starting point; there is a tag for MSO questions about specific SO questions, so asking MSO questions that would belong in it is clearly OK.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and "what is the point" is the perfect starting point. If the prop cannot be answered, that is an answer in itself.

Comment: @Stumbler I'm not a moderator. Given that you thought the subject was pointless, I assumed a ban was what you were hoping for. If you have a solution, then *propose that* instead of posting a rant then being shitty to people who respond to it. Either edit the question or don't, I see no reason to discuss this further.